# Query string undefined when link opened through facebook browser (IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, iframe, query-string

I have a strange scenario happening with my url shared in facebook.

So I have a web url - http://myappurl.com/?id=id_value ,  I use this url inside iframe `<iframe src="http://myappurl.com/?id=id_value"></iframe>` and add it in to my clients CMS page. So public can access my webapp, using http://clientCMSurl.com/appPage

So everything is working as expected, but for one case, when I share 'http://clientCMSurl.com/appPage' url through facebook and users try to open it from facebook in app browser, the query string gives an undefined value.

I have a feeling facebook in app browser is not detecting the query string added in iframe src.

anyone has got idea what is going on with this situation? any work around possible?

EDIT : the query string value has underscore in it. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Do you get any info out of the [FB debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) for the appPage you're sharing?

Comment: I am using sentry logger, and when ever this error throws up, its usually iphone and majority has been showing facebook browser as browser. Only twice it showed safari

Comment: So it doesn't always fail? It's just for some users?

Comment: yes, it doesnt always fail.. mobile users..that too iphone(facebook in app browser) 90% cases..